# How To Get State When VideoView Stop Playing Due To Buffer in middle of playing

Tags: android, android-videoview

I tried the below code but did not worked for me

```
videoView.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int i2) {
                if (what == mediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START){
                    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (what == mediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END){
                    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I have to get every state when videoview stop playing video due to buffering so that I can show progressbar for buffering state.

Any help would be appreciable.